# ¿Hay manera de seleccionar un div por su texto con css?

Tags: html, css

Quisiera saber si es posible que mediante css pueda cambiar el formato de un div pero no por su clase o con id, sino identificándolo a través de su valor. No sé si me explico.

Tengo esto en html:

```
<div>
    <div class="calendar">Mon</div>
    <div class="calendar">Tue</div>
    <div class="calendar">Wed</div>
    <div class="calendar">Thu</div>
    <div class="calendar">Fri</div>
    <div class="calendar">Sat</div>
    <div class="calendar">Sun</div>
</div>
```

y quisiera saber cómo seleccionar en css al *Wed*, algo así como acceder a la clase y dirigirme directo a ese a través de su valor por ejemplo.

Pensaba algo tal que así:

```
.calendar['Wed']{
    color: black;
}
```

Pero pues obvio, no se puede eso.

Comment: los dias de la semana vienen siempre en el mismo orden. En este caso puedes utilizar   .calendar:nth-child(1)  para el primer dia de la semana, .calendar:nth-child(2) para martes ...etc

Answer (score 1):

No creo que se pueda, seria mejor que hicieras esto:

```
<div>
    <div class="calendar-mon">Mon</div>
    <div class="calendar-tue">Tue</div>
    <div class="calendar-wed">Wed</div>
    <div class="calendar-thu">Thu</div>
    <div class="calendar-fri">Fri</div>
    <div class="calendar-sat">Sat</div>
    <div class="calendar-sun">Sun</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola. Muchas gracias por contestar. Igualmente eso es lo que pense en un principio, el problema es que como dije, no me sirve en mi caso cambiarle la clase o ponerle id porque precisamente necesito referirme a traves del valor. Lo que pasa es que en mi trabajo, tengo un script donde genero con un for todos los dias del mes en div's, y pues todos comparten la misma clase, y para cambiarles cosas, necsitaria acceder a ellos precisamente por el valor, pues el for genera 30 div's exactamente iguales donde solo cambia el valor que es 1,2,3,...31  etc. No se si sepas como podria solucionar ese caso

Comment: Dices "tengo un script donde genero con un for todos los dias del mes en div's,". Modifica ese script para modificar la class.

Answer (score 0):

Con css encontrar un texto html desconozco si se pueda, lo unico que se me ocurre es hacerlo mediante JQuery, no es lo que buscas pero puede ser una opción.

En este caso busco ese texto "Wed" mediante un each con JQuery y le agrego la clase **diferente** para darle otro estilo css:

```html
<style>
    .diferente{
        color: red;
    }
</style>
<div>
    <div class="calendar">Mon</div>
    <div class="calendar">Tue</div>
    <div class="calendar">Wed</div>
    <div class="calendar">Thu</div>
    <div class="calendar">Fri</div>
    <div class="calendar">Sat</div>
    <div class="calendar">Sun</div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".calendar" ).each(function( index ) {
        var dia = $( this ).text();
        if(dia=='Wed'){
            console.log('Lo encontre');
            $(this).addClass("diferente");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola lo que puedes hacer es inventarte el atributo **data-value** para el elemento **div.calendar**.

El atributo **data-value** guardaría los días de la semana que se corresponde al texto del div, de esta manera ya podrías usar css para seleccionar el elemento en especifico de esta manera.

```css
.calendar[data-value="Mon"] {
            color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
        <div class="calendar" data-value="Mon">Mon</div>
        <div class="calendar" data-value="Tue">Tue</div>
        <div class="calendar" data-value="Wed">Wed</div>
        <div class="calendar" data-value="Thu">Thu</div>
        <div class="calendar" data-value="Fri">Fri</div>
        <div class="calendar" data-value="Sat">Sat</div>
        <div class="calendar" data-value="Sun">Sun</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Vale mencionar que `data-*` es un atributo html, y que después del guión puede ir cualquier nombre (no solo _value_), teniendo en cuenta las [restricciones](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*).

Comment: @padaleiana es correcto, me olvidé mencionar eso.